# New object with name in variable

Tags: php, laravel, class, object, model

I am trying to initiate an object with a dynamic path. I have the variable `$model` with the model name.

```
$model = "foo";
$class = new \Path\To\$model();
```

I get the error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$model' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

If I try `$class = new \Path\To\{$model}();` 
I get the error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

When I try

```
namespace \App\Models
$class = new $model();
```

I get the error `Class 'foo' not found`

When I try `$class = new \Path\To\foo();` it works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$class = "\Path\To\foo";
$object = new $class();
```

Or:

```
use Path\To\foo;
$class = foo::class;
$object = new $class();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can store path in variable:

```
$path = "\Path\To\\";
```

and then generate class name like this:

```
$className = $path.$model;
$class = new $className();
```